# ASP.NET application works in VS2013 but not when deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, error-handling, bundling-and-minification

Getting the following console error when running a program after it's been deployed that I don't get when using VS2013:

***Note: Updated Console Error output based on using Fiddler (this is the response from the 500 status code***

```
readyState: 4, responseText: "<!DOCTYPE h...", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Se..."}
readyState: 4
responseText: 

"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Error - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Contentbug/css?v=MDbdFKJHBa_ctS5x4He1bMV0_RjRq8jpcIAvPpKiN6U1" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script>


</head>
<body>


    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">



<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>


        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2015 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/bundles/jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1"></script>

    <script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=2Fz3B0iizV2NnnamQFrx-NbYJNTFeBJ2GM05SilbtQU1"></script>



    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">ATTENTION: Please Review Your Custom Email Before Sending</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendButton" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script>
    $('[name="optradio1"]').on('change', function () {
    ....
    });
    </script>

    ...

</body>

</html>
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
```

After reading a few threads about the BundleConfig I changed it so that my bundle name wasn't the same as one of my directory names but that still didn't work as I'm getting the same error, except with the updated name change.

Thoughts/suggestions?

**BundleConfig**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Contentbug/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

**Portion of _layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Contentbug/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

first do these things.

1. Deploy only compiled code.
2. hosting directory should be the root directory(Eg:www.stackoverflow.com),you should not host in sub-directory(Eg:www.stackoverflow.com/supraj).
3. Make sure that you host through FileZilla, a safe method.

If these doesnt work,if you sucessfully runs in localhost,then the only problem is with webconfig file

Comment: I'm hosting through azure (e.g., supraj.azurewebsites.net) -- do #2 and #3 still apply? Also, I'm a bit unsure as to how to deploy only compiled code -- what are the default settings for deploying a website via VS2013? Currently using the 'Web Deploy' publishing method and my configuration settings are set to 'Release'

Comment: After build follow these steps:1.go to->build->publish,(publish in local directory) then your code get compiled and published in the dirctory which you selected while publishing,2.Download filezilla-> https://filezilla-project.org/  3.host through filezilla to azure(yoy may require url,username,password, that you will get in publish *** file in azure)

Comment: Is there a reason why the compiled code can't be deployed via VS2013? Because I'm not sure why asp.net wouldn't allow for a working solution. If we assume the problem is with webconfig what should I be looking to fix?